# Helm 3: Access /files of library chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a library chart that is used as a dependency in multiple other charts. I already share a few named templates using this. I have a few files that I also want to share using the library chart. The content of the file should end up in a config map.

I tried adding a /files directory to the library chart (next to the /templates directory), placed the files inside and used the following named template

```
{{- define "lib-chart.all-files-as-data" -}}
data:
{{- range $path, $bytes := $.Files.Glob "files/*" }}
  {{ $path | base }}: |{{ (tpl ($bytes | toString) $ ) | nindent 6 }}
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

This however only picks up files from the chart which uses the library chart and not the library chart itself.

Is there a way to access the content of the /files folder of a library chart?

Thanks!

Comment: Not that that helps anybody, but FWIW: This is the [intended behaviour](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/library_charts/#library-chart-benefits): "The `.Files` object references the file paths on the parent chart, rather than the path local to the library chart".

If you don't make use of this or any of the other differences between library and application chart, a workaround is to use type `application` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I too came across similar kind of scenario
As i checked in the internet i could able to find a way to access files in library chart
Best possible way is you can create a subchart and extract them to your chart

How to create subchart in helm you see on [1](https://medium.com/craftech/one-chart-to-rule-them-all-3f685e0f25a9)
How to access subchart variables you can read [2](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/)

Comment: That probably defeats the purpose of having it as a dependency. Personally, I want to share the template snippet between multiple sibling charts, so it cannot be a subchart to those.